# Amazon-cognito-identity-js, getting callback.newPasswordRequired is not a function error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Amazon-cognito-identity-js, getting "callback.newPasswordRequired is not a function" error while trying to change the password of an authenticated user

```
const poolData = {
  UserPoolId: 'eu-central-1_XXXXXXX'
  ClientId: '2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxo',
}
const authenticationData = {
  Username: name,
  Password: oldPassword,
}
const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData)
const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData)
const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({ Username: name, Pool: userPool })

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
  onSuccess(result) {
    cognitoUser.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, function (err, passwordChangeResult) {
      if (err) {
        console.warn(err.message || JSON.stringify(err))
      }
      console.warn(`Password change result: ${passwordChangeResult}`)
    })
  },
  onFailure(err) {
    console.warn(err)
  },
})
return null
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that Cognito is returning a newPasswordRequired callback which you have not defined. I would assume the user was created by an Admin API call and not through the Sign Up call. Then upon signing in you are prompted to reset the password.

Taken from here [1], you can implement the newPasswordRequired callback like so.

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            // User authentication was successful
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            // User authentication was not successful
        },
 
        mfaRequired: function(codeDeliveryDetails) {
            // MFA is required to complete user authentication.
            // Get the code from user and call
            cognitoUser.sendMFACode(mfaCode, this)
        },
 
        newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
            // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
            // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
            // authentication.
 
            // the api doesn't accept this field back
            delete userAttributes.email_verified;
 
            // store userAttributes on global variable
            sessionUserAttributes = userAttributes;
        }
    });
```

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: I don't believe the user necessarily was created as an admin. I think it can just be that the user has not changed a temporary password.

Comment: How would the user get a temporary password if they were not created by an Admin?

Comment: I misunderstood your "created the user as an admin" to mean you 'created the user that was of admin status', rather than 'the user was created BY an admin'.

Comment: I should have made that clearer. I will make edit.